# How to post Json in form to controller then save to database

Tags: javascript, php, json, controller, yii2

I have a form with sample table value, my table (id=sampleTbl) hv 2 column name and age. i want to save it to my database table person(id=AI,name,age)when i click submitButton (id=idOfButton)

Below my from code, this my Javascript code :

```
<?php  
$script = <<< JS

$('#idOfButton').click(function(){
    var myTableArray = [];
    $("table#sampleTbl tr").each(function () {
        var arrayOfThisRow = [];
        var tableData = $(this).find('td');
        if (tableData.length > 0) {
            tableData.each(function () {
               arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text());
            });
            myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
        }
    });
    var jsonEncode = JSON.stringify(myTableArray);
    // alert(jsonEncode);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "pTableData=" + jsonEncode,
        success: function(msg){
            // alert(msg);
        },
    });

});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

This is my controller for actionCreate:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Person();

    if(isset($_POST['pTableData'])) {
        $tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['pTableData']);
        $tableData = json_decode($tableData, true);
        $model->name = $tableData[0]['name'];
        $model->age = $tableData[0]['age'];
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    } 
}
```

my form table:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<table id="sampleTbl", class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr id="myRow">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>william</td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Muli</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sukoco</td>
            <td>29</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Create',['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'idOfButton']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

i don't know how to save all value array. when i use like `$tableData[0]['name'];` it just save one first row. how to save all value??

Comment: What response header are you getting on submit?

Comment: when i show to alert its getting like this `[[william,23],[lia,22],[roy,18]] . then want save to database

Comment: Ya but what is the response header? Open DevTools and submit. Then come back here with the response header. It's under Network.

Comment: DevTool in chrome can be opened with F12 .. Open it, fire your submit and under the network tab find the url your calling and look at its response ..

Comment: u must call $model->save() method before exit().Also check not error in model after validating

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 12:14:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache

Comment: Not work @NuriddinRashidov

Comment: can you post result of  print_r(Yii::$app->request->post()) , i think it is not valid sturucture or empty, because u send json encoded data

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov what should i send to my controller?

Comment: U must send to your controller valid array to load your model there : $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(). Because u send json format data, i think it not loaded your model correctly.

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov can you tell me how to work with my table value (id=sampleTbl) then when i click button, its can save to my database?

Comment: ok i think your javascript is working, but your controller not correctly processing, now i will post  answer now

Comment: Also can u post your table view code there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lopping foreach to save an array:

```
foreach ($tableData as $key) {
    $model->isNewRecord = true;
    $model->id = NULL;
    $model->name = $key['name'];
    $model->age = $key['age'];
    $model->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Person();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {            
        $post = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $data = JSON::decode($post, true);
        $model->attributes = $data;//Also check this array, this should be right assoc array, and indexes must be contain model attributes names also
        $response = array();
if($model->save()){
 header('Content-type:application/json');
        $response['success'] = "Everything is good";
   return   $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'message' => $model,
        ]);      
}else{
      $response['error'] = "Data not valid";
   return   $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'message' => $model,
        ]);
}
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    } 
}
```

Can u check out this, if something wrong we will correct them

Comment: have error `$decode = json_decode((string) $json, $asArray)` `case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX: throw new InvalidParamException('Syntax error.');`

Comment: Can you check your view files encoding. Encoding should be utf-8

Comment: im sorry to disturb you again, i had tried this code. Then I change this code a little bit and it's work. but i got new problem can't you help me? i'm just update my code and my new ask @NuriddinRashidov